# Saving List of Strings in Java

Tags: java

am having problem in Saving some data in my Java code.

I have like three different methods which do some respective tasks. Am calling these methods using Hessian from Php client. And am not calling this three methods at a time. Each method will create some arrays(contains strings, int, float), and some time i have to use those arrays which was created my previous methods call in this present method.

Is there any way i can save that Arrays(not in database), may be a List or Array which will not flush the memory unless i say soo..

Example

```
public class top{
    Method1(){

    String[]  stringA = {some string data} ;

    }

    Method2(){

       for(string data : stringA){
          I use array of stringA from method1 without calling the whole method1. I need that string value to be save untill i flush it out.    
       }

    }

}
```

This is not a complete code.. not even a code. Am just trying to explain the issue.

Any help please.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code is not complete, actually its not even there. Posting complete code helps someone trying to answer to understand the problem correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about defining the stringA as a instance variable instead of a local variable ?

Answer (score 1):

You could set up stringA as a local variable to your class.

```
public class SomeClass {
      private String[] stringA;
      public void method1(){
              stingA = "something";
      }
      public void method2(){
              for(string data : stringA){
                I use array of stringA from method1 which out calling the whole method. I  need that string value to be save untill i flush it out.    
              }
      }
```

You could also use a [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), instead of an array for your string.  This will allow you to dynamically grow your list.  If you want to "flush" it, you could just call the clear() method

```
 ArrayList<String> myArr = new ArrayList<String>();
 myArr.add("string1");
 myArr.add("string2");
 //clear the ArrayList
 myArr.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *remember* values between method calls, it should be a instance (class 
level) variable. If yours is a web application, you can use `session` variables.

[Your code is not complete, actually its not even there. Posting complete code helps someone trying to answer to understand the problem correctly.]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about hessian, but it looks like that the component that handles the call is stateless.
I agree with Nivas' answer in this case.

However, should you need extra functionality (search, etc) with the storage and have some hardware resource to spend you can also use something like [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) which have in-memory DB storage (very fast).